# Maven Surefire Plugin not logging from org.junit.jupiter.api package

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm getting some inconsistent behaviour in my unit test logging when either:

- Running tests via IntelliJ's `Run` interface
- Running tests via `mvn test`

I really want to see the following log statements when running `mvn test`, however they do not seem to be visible:

```
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$Random <clinit>
CONFIG: ClassOrderer.Random default seed: 155513463168987
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.InstantiatingConfigurationParameterConverter logSuccessMessage
CONFIG: Using default class orderer 'org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$Random' set via the 'junit.jupiter.testclass.order.default' configuration parameter.
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer$Random <clinit>
CONFIG: MethodOrderer.Random default seed: 155513483010989
```

Inside my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.config.file>
                ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/logging.properties
            </java.util.logging.config.file>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Contents of `src/test/resources/logging.properties`:

```
.level=CONFIG
.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=CONFIG
```

When running tests via IntelliJ's `Run` interface, I can see the following output, with the desired logs towards the bottom:

```
/Users/ian.jones/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.2/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/ian.jones/Development/my-app/target/test-classes/logging.properties -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=61653:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath [omitted for brevity] com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 com.myorg.OpenApiDocsGeneratorTest

May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry loadTestEngines
CONFIG: Discovered TestEngines with IDs: [junit-jupiter (group ID: org.junit.jupiter, artifact ID: junit-jupiter-engine, version: 5.8.2, location: jar:file:/Users/ian.jones/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar!/org/junit/jupiter/engine/JupiterTestEngine.class)]
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderRegistry load
CONFIG: Loaded PostDiscoveryFilter instances: []
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderRegistry load
CONFIG: Loaded LauncherDiscoveryListener instances: []
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderRegistry load
CONFIG: Loaded TestExecutionListener instances: [org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.UniqueIdTrackingListener@2781e022]
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherConfigurationParameters loadClasspathResource
CONFIG: Loading JUnit Platform configuration parameters from classpath resource [file:/Users/ian.jones/Development/my-app/target/test-classes/junit-platform.properties].
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderRegistry load
CONFIG: Loaded LauncherSessionListener instances: []
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherConfigurationParameters loadClasspathResource
CONFIG: Loading JUnit Platform configuration parameters from classpath resource [file:/Users/ian.jones/Development/my-app/target/test-classes/junit-platform.properties].
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$Random <clinit>
CONFIG: ClassOrderer.Random default seed: 155513463168987
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.InstantiatingConfigurationParameterConverter logSuccessMessage
CONFIG: Using default class orderer 'org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$Random' set via the 'junit.jupiter.testclass.order.default' configuration parameter.
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer$Random <clinit>
CONFIG: MethodOrderer.Random default seed: 155513483010989
May 12, 2022 12:00:13 PM org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.InstantiatingConfigurationParameterConverter logSuccessMessage
CONFIG: Using default method orderer 'org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer$Random' set via the 'junit.jupiter.testmethod.order.default' configuration parameter.
```

However, when running `mvn clean install`, the logs which are important to me do not appear:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ my-app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] May 12, 2022 12:10:06 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry loadTestEngines
[ERROR] CONFIG: Discovered TestEngines with IDs: [junit-jupiter (group ID: org.junit.jupiter, artifact ID: junit-jupiter-engine, version: 5.8.2, location: jar:file:/Users/ian.jones/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar!/org/junit/jupiter/engine/JupiterTestEngine.class)]
[ERROR] May 12, 2022 12:10:06 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderRegistry load
[ERROR] CONFIG: Loaded PostDiscoveryFilter instances: []
[ERROR] May 12, 2022 12:10:06 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderRegistry load
[ERROR] CONFIG: Loaded LauncherDiscoveryListener instances: []
[ERROR] May 12, 2022 12:10:06 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderRegistry load
[ERROR] CONFIG: Loaded TestExecutionListener instances: [org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.UniqueIdTrackingListener@76c3e77a]
[ERROR] May 12, 2022 12:10:06 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherConfigurationParameters loadClasspathResource
[ERROR] CONFIG: Loading JUnit Platform configuration parameters from classpath resource [file:/Users/ian.jones/Development/my-app/target/test-classes/junit-platform.properties].
[ERROR] May 12, 2022 12:10:06 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderRegistry load
[ERROR] CONFIG: Loaded LauncherSessionListener instances: []
[INFO] Running ...
```

I have tried changing the version of `maven-surefire-plugin` to `3.0.0-M4` or `3.0.0-M6` but in both cases, this results in *all* the CONFIG logs disappearing from the output.

I have also tried explicitly setting the handlers for the classes in question, e.g.:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer$Random.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

But all this does is result in duplicate output log lines when running tests with `Run`, and doesn't change the output when running tests with `mvn test`.

Clearly it's partially working in that it is reading `logging.config` in both cases (if I remove this file, all CONFIG logs disappear when running `mvn test`) - but I have no idea why the behaviour is different, or how to fix that.

## EDIT: Minimal `pom.xml` file

Here's a minimal `pom.xml` demonstrating the issue (I'm using Maven 3.8.5)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>surefire-problem-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.config.file>
                            ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/logging.properties
                        </java.util.logging.config.file>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction

Let's consider the following versions as the current versions:

- Maven Surefire Plugin `3.0.0-M7`.
- JUnit `5.8.2`.

## Root cause analysis

### Analysis

Maven Surefire Plugin uses its `JUnitPlatformProvider` class. It may be observed in the output right before the «Tests» section:

```
<…>
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) @ the-project ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
<…>
```

Please, see the implementation of the `JUnitPlatformProvider.setupJunitLogger()` method: [maven-surefire/JUnitPlatformProvider.java at surefire-3.0.0-M7 · apache/maven-surefire](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-3.0.0-M7/surefire-providers/surefire-junit-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/surefire/junitplatform/JUnitPlatformProvider.java#L154-L161):

```
private static void setupJunitLogger()
{
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( "org.junit" );
    if ( logger.getLevel() == null )
    {
        logger.setLevel( WARNING );
    }
}
```

Please, note the condition:

```
logger.getLevel() == null
```

Please, see the documentation of the [`Logger.getLevel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLevel--) method:

> public [Level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html) getLevel()
>
> Get the log Level that has been specified for this Logger. The result may be null, which means that this logger's effective level will be inherited from its parent.
>
> Returns:
>
> this Logger's level

Please, note the statement:

> The result may be null, which means that this logger's effective level will be inherited from its parent.

### Analysis summary

This is (see the «Analysis» subsection) why:

1. A parent logger configuration is not taken into account by Maven Surefire Plugin.

   It does not seem to be a user-friendly behavior.
   Maybe, it is worth reporting it as a Maven Surefire Plugin issue.
2. It is necessary to introduce the explicit logger configuration for the `org.junit` package.

## Solution

It is necessary to introduce the explicit logger configuration for the `org.junit` package:

```
org.junit.level=CONFIG
```

## Follow-up: Checking provided complete `pom.xml` file

I have used the provided complete `pom.xml` file with the following preconditions.

I had used the same preconditions to test the solution.

### Preconditions

#### Added test classes

Added 3 test classes annotated with `@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.Random.class)` like this one:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.Random.class)
public class Application1Test {
    @Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue2() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

#### Enabled parallel test execution

The content of the `src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties` file:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=concurrent
```

#### Added JUnit-related log level

The content of the `src/test/resources/logging.properties`:

```
.level=CONFIG
.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=CONFIG
org.junit.level=CONFIG
```

### Output

```
$ ./mvnw clean test 2>&1 | grep -F 'MethodOrderer.Random'
CONFIG: MethodOrderer.Random default seed: 7225497639767
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me - just upgrading the plugin to version 3.0.0-M7 causes the same problem I mentioned with versions 3.0.0-M4 and 3.0.0-M6 (all existing visible CONFIG logs disappear completely).

I cannot see why your solution doesn't work, but I'm not sure if it's possible to debug the surefire plugin to have a look at what's happening when doing a mvn clean test. I wonder if a clue to the problem I'm having is the mislabelling of the CONFIG logs as "ERROR" in the output I posted above.

Comment: @Ian250221, could you please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (by updating the question)? It seems that providing the entire content of the `pom.xml` file would be enough. Additionally, could you please specify the currently used Maven version?

Comment: Done - I'm using Maven 3.8.5

Comment: Dear @Ian250221, Please, see the updated answer.

Comment: Dear @Ian250221, Could you please run the follow-up example (taking into account the preconditions) and provide the result of the run?

Comment: Sorry, your initial solution was actually working with my minimal example, I had just made a mistake in logging.properties. The reason it wasn't working for my project is that I was extending a parent pom which was also defining the maven-surefire-plugin and setting redirectTestOutputToFile to true. The logs I was expecting to see in the console were in fact ending up inside target/surefire-reports/null-output.txt. Anyway, I'm happy to accept your answer as it has solved my problem. Thank you!